# Fréchet distance of 2 trajectories

Tags: python, distance, curve

Good Day,

I have two different paths in a 2D plane. I want to compare these two paths with the Fréchet Distance.

I know some points of the trajectories, each is connected to another point with a straight line.

What's the smartest way to get the Fréchet Distance? Any hints? I'm working in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implemetation from here https://pypi.org/project/frechetdist/ or from here https://pypi.org/project/similaritymeasures/

Generally speaking, when you measure Frechet distance you can always (in the terminology of walking person and dog)

- A.  move person further,
- B. move your dog further,
- C. move both further,

At each step you can do A, B, C get minimum(A,B,C) and append to results list. After finishing both trajectories get max() of your results list.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the implementation in https://pypi.org/project/frechetdist/ is limited to scenarios where the 2 paths must have equal lengths.

I found this repo: https://github.com/joaofig/discrete-frechet where the author made some improvements over the dynamic programming approach.